# I need to update jQuery version for drupal manually?

Tags: javascript

For updating the drupal core jquery file i used the jquery_update contributed module. This module help me a lot to use some of the new function/method of jquery.

But In my view i'm using ajax for pagination and exposed filter form submission. My view containing very bulky data so most of the time most of the browser giving me a script error saying - script is unresponsive, file is ...jquery.min.js

And as my table data is growing up this script error is coming up frequently (that's halt every thing on browser).

Actually this file came into the picture when i install the jquery_update module. By my personal experience i know the reason (basically file conflict).

So i just want to know how to replace the drupal default jquery file with jquery's latest version file manually.

Any suggestion or guidance will really gonna help me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

1- @see `/misc/jquery.js`

2- its better to add ur jquery to your theme .info file

- go to your theme folder
- insert your jquery file into the same folder of your theme (E.g theme name new_jquery.js)
- in the same directory open yourThemName.info file
- add this line  `scripts[] = new_jquery.js`

3- its not prefered to use Jquery 1.6 with Drupal 6

4- use [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) to avoid conflict

Answer (score 1):

First have a look at [this post on Drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/1067290), some of the posters claim to have got jQuery 1.5.1 working with Drupal 6.

It's pretty much definite that you won't get the latest version of jQuery into Drupal 6, I've heard of people managing to get as far as v1.4.4 (and now v.1.5.1) but the differences between 1.3.2 and 1.6.4 and just too much for Drupal to handle automatically.

The main problem seems to be that installing any version of jQuery >1.3.2 breaks a lot of the core javascript functions (including views). Some people mitigate this to some extent by dropping a later version of the library into sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace (overwriting the existing jquery.min.js file) and then hacking the jquery_update module itself to only preform a replacement on non-admin pages (i.e. those that wouldn't suffer from needing Drupal's default jQuery version). See my answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636171/jquery-this-legacy-scoping/7650467#comment9307675_7650467) for more details, and also run [this Google search](http://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1&nord=1#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&safe=off&nord=1&site=webhp&source=hp&q=drupal+jquery+update+1.4&pbx=1&oq=drupal+jquery+update+1.4&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=39l3644l0l3709l8l4l0l0l0l2l160l443l0.3l3l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=42b2570fa124b3ec&ion=1&biw=1920&bih=851) and have a look at the first 5 or 6 links there, they have some very good information.

To be honest though I don't think installing an updated version of jQuery will help with this problem anyway, if your scripts are becoming unresponsive then the problem is that the PHP script at the other end is taking too long to respond...I'm almost positive there's nothing jQuery will be able to do about that. Could you look at reducing the number of items on each of views pages or reducing the complexity of the view's database query instead?