# How to include jquery from URL in custom module?

Tags: 6, javascript

I've got a question about module building and including JS.
I'm working on a D6 custom module, and for JS files I'm including from within my mod
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'ingsavingsmap') .'/js/effects.js');
works just fine.

The question I have is: I'm trying to include jquery from the jquery site.
I know:
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'ingsavingsmap') .'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-        latest.js');

is very wrong for a number of reasons, but I don't know how to go about adding JS from a URL.
Also, is it advisable to event be doing it this way? or should I just keep it all within the mod.

Any help or direction to documentation would be appreciate
Thanks!
Steph

Comment: I think you'll really struggle to get the latest version of jQuery into a Drupal 6 site (without getting a lot of JS errors). What are you using that depends on the latest version?

Comment: I've got a lot of other effects, and yes I know it's against the Drupal Way. I'm hoping that because the mod produces a page its by itself enough to not cause conflicts. Any Ideas?

Comment: It's been discussed quite a few times (more for D7 than D6) and I think the [jQuery multi](http://drupal.org/project/jqmulti) module is probably the best bet. But these posts (and their various links) might help too: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12911/i-need-to-update-jquery-version-for-drupal-manually, http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28820/how-do-i-update-jquery-to-the-latest-version-i-can-download. I love that you capitalised "Drupal Way" by the way, sounds like a good title for a book...

Answer (score 1):

**D7**

For those who need to do this in D7, its as simple as

```
drupal_add_js('http://example.com/example.js', 'external');
```

**D6**

I can not take credit for this example but found this to be rather nice and easy way of dealing with external js files.

```
$external_js = 'http://www.example.com/a.js';
drupal_add_js('document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src=\''. $external_js . '\' type=\'text/javascript\'%3E%3C/script%3E"));', 'inline');
```

Found this via http://www.wootenswebdesign.com/load-external-js-file-drupal-6

Comment: I'm afraid it really isn't that simple. Drupal already includes jQuery so without extra work you'll get conflicts

Comment: ugh. that is what i get for again not reading the whole question. i see where i made a mistake. however, this should still work just nto with including jquery.

Comment: Yeah for including anything other than jQuery externally this is spot on :)

Comment: I agree with clive on the conflicts, and I know I'm going to have to do a bunch of troubleshooting. Right now this actually works "drupal_add_js('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js');"
I do have some stuff to figure out still but I'll let you know wat happens and if it's successful or not, as well as accept an answer.
Thanks all! I really appreciate the help!